# How do I transfter files to this SunOS server?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, server, linux, ftp

According to the admin of the webserver, I should be able to use Filezilla to transfer files to the server but I am getting an error.

First: I'm able to connect to the remote server using X-Win32 ssh, from my Windows 7 machine:

```
SunOS server.edu 5.10 Generic_120011-14 sun4v sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5220
System type is SUN4V with 65408 MB of memory.

server.edu(1):
```

Next, I set up Filezilla for transfering files sftp - using [these directions](http://www.upenn.edu/computing/help/doc/ftp/filezillasftp.html) I found on the web.

However, this is what I get:

```
Status:    Connecting to server.edu:12345...
Response:    fzSftp started
Command:    open "gmcnulty@server.edu" 12345
Error:    Connection timed out
Error:    Could not connect to server
Status:    Waiting to retry...
Status:    Connecting to server.edu:12345...
Response:    fzSftp started
Command:    open "gmcnulty@server.edu" 12345
Error:    Connection timed out
Error:    Could not connect to server
```

Any point in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: that was it, needed to be port 22! Thanks, please put that as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1):

IF you're using SSH, verify it's port 22, not "12345" and that the ports are open from the WAN? (If it is actually port 12345, make sure that it's open).